# ¿Por qué me aparece separación entre DIV?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

¿Por qué me aparece separación entre DIV en Bootstrap4?

```css
.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  /* Green */
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bg-2 {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  /* Dark Blue */
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bg-3 {
  background-color: #ffff8f;
  /* Amarillo */
  color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
  <h3>Javier García</h3>
  <img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12814350_10208758265299127_3760798125067884543_n.jpg?oh=835754216488abcecccea0d374b33411&oe=5AC657AB" class="profile-image rounded-circle" alt="Javier">
  <p>Economista, Master en Banca y Finanzas, empleado de banca, fundador de <a href="www.paredesdepapel.com">Paredes de papel</a> y aprendiz de diseño web</p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-2">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h3>Mis proyectos online</h3>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Nidala</li>
    <li>Paredes de papel</li>
    <li>Mi web personal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <h3>Contacto</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: Este es el css:
.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-2 {
  background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-3 {
  background-color: #ffff8f; /* Amarillo */
  color: #555555;
}

Comment: Quizás falte un poco de contexto para poder ayudarte con tu pregunta. ¿quién genera ese código html? ¿en qué contexto o con qué script o programa?

Comment: A qué te referís con separación? Los `h3` tienen por defecto `margin-top` eso seguro genera un espacio entre los `div`.

Comment: no esta nada claro sobre tu pregunta, mejoralo con una descripcion especificando a que separacion te refieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás viendo es un efecto de los márgenes colapsables ([*collapsing margins*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) en inglés). Traducción algo libre:

> ### Colapsamiento de márgenes
>
> En CSS, los márgenes adyacentes de dos o más elementos (que pueden o no ser hermanos) pueden combinarse para formar un margen único. Se dice que los márgenes que se combinan de esta manera se colapsan, y el margen combinado resultante se denomina margen colapsado.
>
> Los márgenes verticales adyacentes se colapsan, excepto en dos casos:
>
> - Los márgenes del elemento raíz no se colapsan.
> - Si los márgenes superior e inferior de un elemento con `clear` son contiguos, sus márgenes se colapsan con los márgenes adyacentes de los hermanos siguientes, pero el margen resultante no se colapsa con el margen inferior del elemento contenedor (padre).
>
> Los márgenes horizontales nunca colapsan.

El problema con el código compartido es que el último elemento de los `div` (un `p` y un `ul` respectivamente) tiene un margen inferior (de `1rem`) que se colapsa.

Para solucionar esa separación, podrías intentar alguno de estos dos métodos:

- Quitar el margen para el último elemento. En este caso no quedaría espacio alguna al final del contenedor. Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

  ```css
  .profile-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  /* quitarle el margen de abajo al ultimo elemento */
  .bg-1 > :last-child, 
  .bg-2 > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .bg-1 {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    /* Green */
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .bg-2 {
    background-color: #474e5d;
    /* Dark Blue */
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .bg-3 {
    background-color: #ffff8f;
    /* Amarillo */
    color: #555555;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
    <h3>Javier García</h3>
    <img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12814350_10208758265299127_3760798125067884543_n.jpg?oh=835754216488abcecccea0d374b33411&oe=5AC657AB" class="profile-image rounded-circle" alt="Javier">
    <p>Economista, Master en Banca y Finanzas, empleado de banca, fundador de <a href="www.paredesdepapel.com">Paredes de papel</a> y aprendiz de diseño web</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-2">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Mis proyectos online</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Nidala</li>
      <li>Paredes de papel</li>
      <li>Mi web personal</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <h3>Contacto</h3>

  </div>
  ```
- Añadir un borde invisible al padre, y así se extenderá hasta incluir el margen del último elemento. Aquí puedes verlo

  ```css
  .profile-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .bg-1 {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    /* Green */
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  }

  .bg-2 {
    background-color: #474e5d;
    /* Dark Blue */
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  }

  .bg-3 {
    background-color: #ffff8f;
    /* Amarillo */
    color: #555555;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
    <h3>Javier García</h3>
    <img src="https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12814350_10208758265299127_3760798125067884543_n.jpg?oh=835754216488abcecccea0d374b33411&oe=5AC657AB" class="profile-image rounded-circle" alt="Javier">
    <p>Economista, Master en Banca y Finanzas, empleado de banca, fundador de <a href="www.paredesdepapel.com">Paredes de papel</a> y aprendiz de diseño web</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-2">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Mis proyectos online</h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Nidala</li>
      <li>Paredes de papel</li>
      <li>Mi web personal</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <h3>Contacto</h3>

  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Los div con col-* vienen con una separación de margin-left y margin-right de 15px por defecto. Si quieres solucionar eso dales css a esos div con margin-left y margin-right de 0px

Comment: No tiene ningún `.col` en su `HTML`.